# Sign digital signature using PHP

Tags: php

How to sign digital signature using PHP?

Answer (score 1):

Right from the documentation for [openssl_sign()](https://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-sign.php)

```
//data you want to sign
$data = 'my data';

//create new private and public key
$new_key_pair = openssl_pkey_new(array(
    "private_key_bits" => 2048,
    "private_key_type" => OPENSSL_KEYTYPE_RSA,
));

openssl_pkey_export($new_key_pair, $private_key_pem);

//create signature
openssl_sign($data, $signature, $private_key_pem, OPENSSL_ALGO_SHA256);

echo base64_encode($signature);
```

Of course, if you already have a private key you can skip generating one and just use it as the `$private_key_pem` parameter in `openssl_sign()` directly.

Comment: I'm not sure a signature is really what you're looking for. Are you trying to set up https?

Comment: I have xml file and digital signature in my end (Client), Now, the server wants to verify the digital signature and xml on me first before it can invoke any transactions. Now, the problem is I don't know how I will sign the xml before they can verify.

Comment: In summary, I will need to digitally sign the request data (XML) then they will verify the signature, so confusing in my part because, they gave a digital signature/certificate. I don't know what's the use of this.

Comment: PS. The XML must generate a private key then that's the time the request data would be verified by the server with XML and digital signature they have. I hope you understand, As I mentioned, I'm sorry for being this way, this is my first time doing this securities in PHP and I don't have an idea.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Do you have a private key already, or do you need to create one? If you need to create one, using the code above should work fine. Just set the `$data` variable to be the XML string you need to sign.

Comment: I have public key (.cer) and private key (.pfx) those are the digital signatures that I want to encrypt but its up to me which one will I use. The process here. I have xml and signatures, I will need to encrypt the signatures and embed to xml thats the time that I can create a request and send to server.

Comment: Do you want to encrypt something or do you want to sign something? Those are different things.

Comment: Hi, good questions, what is the difference of signing and encrypting? And for your question, I need to sign xml data (I have xml data to request) and for signature it must be encrypted. THANKS

Comment: You can encrypt with either [openssl_public_encrypt](https://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-public-encrypt.php) or [openssl_private_encrypt](https://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-private-encrypt.php)

Comment: I received an error Warning: openssl_pkey_export(): cannot get key from parameter 1 in Warning: openssl_sign(): supplied key param cannot be coerced into a private key

Answer (score 0):

You can use **tcpdf class** for this.
https://tcpdf.org/examples/example_001/